# Enable Mixed Mode debugging in VS 2017

Tags: python, visual-studio-2017, mixed-mode

I'm trying to do mixed mode debugging, Python & C++, using VS2017.

This page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-in-mixed-mode?view=vs-2019 says "Select Python/Native Debugging" for Debugger to Launch.  This doesn't show up on my list of debugger choices.  Any idea what I missed in the setup?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the python development workload AND the python native development tools from the optional modules list. You can find these in the visual studio installer.